# Coutning Table Using Summation and Inner for loop

Tags: c, algorithm, loops

I want to build a counting table from 1 to 20 using inner for loop but instead of using multiplication, I want to use summation to build up my answer.

I wrote this code and for only number 1, I can see the correct answer.
From number 2, I see that it adds up from the 10th multiplication.

I want to correct my logic error here in this code and any help is highly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m , n=1;
    int i;

    m = 0;
    for(n = 1; n <= 20; n++){
        for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            m = m + n;
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n", n, i, m);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int m, n, i;

    for (n = 1; n <= 20; n++) {
        // reset m before additions
        m = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            m += n;
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n", n, i, m);
        }
    }

    return (0);
}
```